# Highcharts legend custom css style / format using only highcharts options

Tags: javascript, styles, highcharts, legend

I've tried lots of combinations in the legend options of the highcharts object, however I was not able to successfully realize the exact design that the designer made.

What I need is to be able to have a legend that looks exactly like this...
[Wanted legend layout](http://twitpic.com/9jtn4q)

But the closest result that I achieved with the legend options available was this...
[The closest legend layout I could achieve](http://twitpic.com/9jtorm)

The properties I used within the highchart object definition were:

```
legend: {
    enabled: graphProperties.legend.enabled,
    backgroundColor: ...
    borderRadius: ...
    verticalAlign: ...
    align: ...
    borderWidth: ...
    x: ...
    y: ... }
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: If possible can you throw up a sample set of data and code on jsFiddle?

Comment: Sure, I'll try ass soon as I get back to work, since I cannot get to my work computer right now.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe you can use this as a starting point.

http://jsfiddle.net/DqAqu/4/

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({

        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container', 
            backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5', 
            plotBackgroundColor: '#FFFFFF'
        },

        symbols: [ 'square', 'square' ], 

        legend: {
            backgroundColor: '#F5F5F5',
            layout: 'horizontal',
            floating: true,
            align: 'left',
            verticalAlign: 'top',
            x: 60,
            y: 1,
            shadow: false, 
            border: 0, 
            borderRadius: 0, 
            borderWidth: 0
        },

        xAxis: {
            categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4], 
            color: '#47D147'            
        }, {
            data: [95.6, 54.4, 29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1], 
            color: '#19A3FF'            
        }]
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is quite far from what I need. I can't use float: true, because my chart should never be covered by the legend. In your example also, the legend isn't aligned left totally. I even used onShow and onRedraw events to manipulate the css of the legend using jQuery but with no success. I tried testing and manipulating the CSS style of the legend on spot with firebug, but even that didn't work. No effect at all! The best I could achieve was to set the legend width, but was unable to get the width of the same size as the chart container. I did that onShow event also, but no success.